# Why are Windows 8 updates on startup?

Tags: windows-8, boot, windows-update, shutdown

*I did a big step from Windows XP to Windows 8 recently. so maybe this question is for windows 7 too?*

In Windows XP, Windows installs updates at shutdowm. But in Windows 8, Windows installs updates on startup, then shuts down and starts up again. Why is that?

Maybe I talk to myself when I say it is more important to boot the computer quickly rather than shut it down quickly.

Comment: Windows 7 also does it. I don't know why but I presume there's a technical reason for it, such as the files were locked when the system was running and were going to remain locked while it was shutting down, or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Windows XP memory has gone quite bad, but i remember that on Windows Vista and Windows 7, updates were first downloaded and then installed. For updates which required a restart to be completely installed, they would begin when you click on Restart or Shutdown. You could see some progress during the shut-down process. However, they would continue on start-up and finally complete. So if you look at it, updates were installed during the shutdown-startUp cycle. AFAIK this continues to be the case with Windows 8. I'm on Win 8 Pro and update process looks familiar to me.